# Simple mathematical mystery from Excel

Tags: excel, math, discrete-mathematics

I got a problem to understand on first sight simple to reproduce mathematical problem as follows:
[The Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3if2.png)
The first 5 rows of columns A-D are simple numbers. The first 5 rows of column E  are E=D/C. The first 5 rows of column F are F=(B-A)+(A*E).
Then the sums row sums up A-D. The number G (just under) equals to Sum(D)/Sum(C) and consequently I=(sum(B)-sum(A))+(sum(A)*G). H=sum(the previous F rows).

Now the question is: Why doesn't H equal I ??? That is, why in this case doesn't sum of partial results equal to the calculation made from sums of the columns?

Comment: Please don't hide a table in an image behind a link.

Comment: I would love to but stack overflow says I cannot do otherwise. Sorry for the inconvenience of a link, not an intention.

Comment: I understand that you don't have the reputation to post an image, and that markdown doesn't let you do a table.  But you could have formatted the numbers as a code sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont mess with calculation precedence!

Let's simplify this using only two rows:

[image]

`F1` is `=B1-A1+A1*D1/C1` and `F2` is `=B2-A2+A2*D2/C2`

So `F4`, your `H`, is `=B1-A1+A1*D1/C1+B2-A2+A2*D2/C2`

`F6`, your `I`, is `=B1+B2-A1-A2+((A1+A2)*(D1+D2)/(C1+C2))`

You claim, `H` should be equal `I`:

`B1-A1+A1*D1/C1+B2-A2+A2*D2/C2 = B1+B2-A1-A2+((A1+A2)*(D1+D2)/(C1+C2))`

Subtract B1, B2,  and add up A1, A2 on both sides:

`A1*D1/C1+A2*D2/C2 = ((A1+A2)*(D1+D2)/(C1+C2))`

This is simply not true.

Answer (score 0):

In your table `E7 = D7 / C7` and this is different from `sum(E1:E5)` because of the formulas involved. The value `293.5` corresponds to the case when `E7 = sum(E1:E5)` and the value `296.4` to the case where `E7 = D7/C7`.

**UPDATE**

The two formulas for `F7` you are trying to compare are mathematically different.

One is

```
(B1-A1) + A1*E1 + (B2-A2) + A2*E2 + ... + (B5-A5) + A5*E5
           = (B7-A7) + (A1*E1 + ... + A5*E5)
           = (B7-A7) + (A1*D1/C1 + ... + A5*D5/C5)          (1)
```

and the other

```
(B7-A7) + A7 *(D1+D2+D3+D4+D5)/(C1+C2+C3+C4+C5)             (2)
```

Only the first term `(B7-A7)` is the same in both expressions. The rest is different. In (1) you first multiply and divide `A`<sub>i</sub>`*D`<sub>i</sub>`/C`<sub>i</sub> and then sum. In (2) you first sum the `A`<sub>i</sub>, `D`<sub>i</sub> and `C`<sub>i</sub> and then multiply the sums.

Comment: The picture did not match my description in some points. I updated it, Can you take a look again pls Leonardo?

Comment: Thanks for all your comments, now it is clearer to me why the small discrepancy occurred.